# preventing git merge to master branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I am using branching to create and deploy custom instances of out platform. These instances usually start as a branch from the 'master' branch, get customized somewhat, get deployed into testing and production, and finally archived.

If new features or bug fixes are added into the master I would like to be able to fetch/merge them into my project instances (branches), but I almost never want to merge back changes from the branches to the master. This occurred recently by mistake and has created some serious headaches. A git pull to update a repository merged everything into the master branch and then was pushed back into the main repo.

Is there any easy way to forbid merging back into the master? Or at least requiring some --force flag?

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure no merging into the master from other branches by forbidding anyone to push the master branch. A person with authority can do that. Gitolite is something that allows you to finely tune access to branches. You can also write your own server side hooks and reject updating of the master branch unless you are a specific user.

Comment: what's with the downvote? Let me know what's wrong with my answer and I'll clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Adam, I don't think that I downvoted your answer. I'm actually pretty sure that I upped it. But if I made a mistake sorry. Also Gitolite is a bit too much for our needs right now, but I can see how the server side hooks could do what I need.

Comment: gitolite is surprisingly easy. I do recommend you give it a spin. The biggest benefit is that it greatly simplifies key management. Oh, and I didn't mean that it was you that downvoted. You can't get that info. I was really curious why my answer did not do satisfy someone or if I had a mistake in it.

Answer (score 1):

Git is quite happy to work with multiple remote repositories.

I would recommend using one remote repository for *each* custom instance. This would not change your workflow, as Git can merge any two branches together regardless of origin.

To update a "custom instance" with bug fixes from your "master remote" you'd type something like

```
git checkout <custom-branch>
git fetch main
git merge main/master
```

where `main` is the remote repository you are referring to as `master`(I changed the name to avoid confusion between a branch and a remote)

For your local branches, *do not* specify `main` as the remote tracking branch, instead specify an instance-specific remote. i.e. one remote repository per custom instance.

To push changes to your custom instance, use

```
git push
```

In the rare case where you need to push changes upstream to the "master" branch use

```
git push main
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly how we work, but somehow someone did a git push --all and then a git pull or something like that which merged everything. Or at lest that what I understand.

Comment: Don't use git pull. Git fetch first and then act accordingly to the updated remote tracking branches with merging, rebasing or resetting local branches.

Comment: I agree with Adam, that's the way I do it. Just make sure you do not rebase after you push your changes or things get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid merging into master, you could use pre-merge hook to forbid it.

Comment: I find no evidence that there is any such thing as a pre-merge hook.